# Protobuf builder: set string field without memory allocation

Tags: java, string, memory-management, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have to create and write huge amount of protobuf messages, which contain string field (different for each message). I create a protobuf.Builder and reuse it for creating all messages, setting this string field and invoking method build(). I have bytes as input, e.g. for each message I have byte[], which should be set to string-field. So the question is - how can I set byte[] to string field of the builder without new memory allocation?

As far as I understand, when use protobuf builder in java there are two ways to set string-field:

1. set(String field)
2. set(ByteString field)

The first one requires to make a new object String from byte[], and that's why new memory allocation.
The second one requires to use some method of ByteString, for example ByteString.copyFrom(byte[]), but this method (as all other similar methods of ByteString) does not use exists byte array, and creates new one instead. 
So, is there any workaround about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only interested in writing the messages out, you could go really low level and use `CodedOutputStream.writeBytes`. It's not how I normally prefer to use protocol buffers, but that's a different matter.

Fundamentally, the problem is that `byte[]` is mutable, and protobuf messages in Java are meant to be *immutable*... which means you *have* to take a copy, basically. Even though the builders themselves are mutable, `bytes` and `string` fields are seen as atomic, effectively. (So you can change a builder to have a different byte string or string value for a field, but not mutate the byte string or string itself.)

You should absolutely *not* be using a `string` field for data that isn't text though. You should use a `bytes` field for arbitrary binary data. A `string` field is expected to contain UTF-8-encoded text.